# Separate discrete and continuous variables

Tags: python, dataframe, numerical

I know how to separate numerical and categorical data as follows:

```
num_data = [cname for cname in df.columns if df[cname].dtypes == 'object']
cat_data = [cname for cname in df.columns if df[cname].dtypes in ['int64', 'float64']]
```

Now I want to separate my numerical variables into `discrete` and `continuous`. How do I do that?

Comment: How do you define discrete and continuous variables? // Since you have discrete observations, there is an argument that all of your variables are discrete.

Comment: Discrete as in 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 111.0 and so on. Continuous as in 1.1, 1.199, 444.34 and so on.

Comment: Wouldn‘t be a int column „discrete“ and „continuous“ float?

Comment: In my case, 1.0 is a discrete variable and float at the same time.

Comment: [How to test if my data is discrete or continuous?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12273/260797)